# Modifying the Create Account Program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a student currently learning C++ and I need some help. I am currently working on a textbook exercise from the book Murach's C++ Programming. I am working on Exercise 7-2 (second exercise in chapter 7). The instructions for the program are here: [Exercise 7-2 instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OJmA.jpg) I've managed to make sense of most of it, but I am currently stuck on step 9. I know how to call functions, but when I run the program, it only allows me to enter my full name. After I do that, the program ends without letting me enter my password or email. And yes I have added a return value to my variables as needed. How can I make the program let me enter my full name, password and email like it's supposed to? Nothing that I've tried seems to work. I've tried returning a value of 0, I've tried making a local variable and then adding the return value to said variable, but none of that worked. Please help me understand what I'm supposed to do as I'm still new to C++ and have a lot to learn. By the way, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios as my IDE.

Here's the code that I have so far for my main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "validation.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Create Account\n\n";

// get full name and parse first name
string full_name;
string first_name;
bool valid_name = false;
while (!valid_name) {
    cout << "Enter full name: ";
    getline(cin, full_name);

    // strip whitespace from front
    int i = full_name.find_first_not_of(" \n\t");
    if (i > -1) {
        full_name = full_name.substr(i);
    }

    // get first name
    int space_index = full_name.find(' ');
    if (space_index == -1) {
        cout << "You must enter your full name. Please try again.\n";
    }
    else {
        first_name = full_name.substr(0, space_index);
        valid_name = true;
    }
}
cout << endl;

bool validation::is_valid_password(string password);

bool validation::is_valid_email(string email);

// make sure first name uses initial cap
char letter = first_name[0];
first_name[0] = toupper(letter);
for (int i = 1; i < first_name.length(); ++i) {
    letter = first_name[i];
    first_name[i] = tolower(letter);
}

// display welcome message
cout << "Hi " << first_name << ",\n"
    << "Thanks for creating an account!\n\n";
}
```

And the code I have so far with the validation.cpp implementation file:

```
#include "validation.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace validation;

bool validation::is_valid_password(string password) {
bool valid_password = false;
while (!valid_password) {

    valid_password = true;

    cout << "Enter password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

    if (password.length() < 8) {
        cout << "Password must be at least 8 characters.\n";
        valid_password = false;
    }

    int index = password.find_first_of("0123456789");
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "Password must include a number.\n";
        valid_password = false;
    }

    bool special_character = false;
    for (char c : password) {
        if (ispunct(c)) {
            special_character = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!special_character) {
        cout << "Password must include a special character.\n";
        valid_password = false;
    }

    if (!valid_password) {
        cout << "Please try again.\n";
    }
    else {
        password = password.substr(0, index);
        valid_password = true;
    }
}
cout << endl;
return false;
}

bool validation::is_valid_email(string email) {
bool valid_email = false;
while (!valid_email) {

    valid_email = true;

    cout << "Enter email: ";
    getline(cin, email);

    int at_index = email.find('@');
    if (at_index == -1) {
        cout << "The email must include an at character (@).\n";
        valid_email = false;
    }

    int dot_index = email.rfind('.');
    if (dot_index == -1) {
        cout << "The email must include a dot operator (.).\n";
        valid_email = false;
    }

    bool valid_chars = true;
    for (char c : email) {
        if (c != '@' && c != '.' && c != '_' && c != '-') {
            if (!isalnum(c)) {
                valid_chars = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (at_index == 0) {
        cout << "The local part of the email must include at least one character.\n";
        valid_email = false;
    }

    if (dot_index - at_index == 1) {
        cout << "The server name of the email must include at least one character.\n";
        valid_email = false;
    }

    if (email.length() - dot_index - 1 != 3 && email.length() - dot_index - 1 != 2) {
        cout << "The domain name of the email must have two or three characters.\n";
        valid_email = false;
    }
    if (!valid_email) {
        cout << "Please try again.\n";
    }
    else {
        email = email.substr(0, at_index);
        email = email.substr(0, dot_index);
        valid_email = true;
    }

}
cout << endl;
return false;
}
```

And the code I have for the validation header file:

```
#ifndef T_FRYE_VALIDATION_H
#define T_FRYE_VALIDATION_H
#endif // !T_FRYE_VALIDATION_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace validation {
  bool is_valid_password(string password);
  bool is_valid_email(string email);
}
```

I know that this is a lot to read, and I'm really sorry about that, but I'm at a loss as to what to do next. If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure everything is correctly included and linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls to your validation functions are malformed.  You attempt to call the code

`validation::isvalid_password();` from main but what you provide instead is:

`bool validation::is_valid_password(string password);`

`bool validation::is_valid_email(string email);`

which are declarations.  You need to actually call the code you want.

```
string password;
string email;
validation::isvalid_password(password);
validation::is_valid_email(email);
```

Comment: I used this code in the main function and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think these two lines do inside the `main()` function?

```cpp
int main()
{
// ...
bool validation::is_valid_password(string password);
bool validation::is_valid_email(string email);
// ...
}
```

That is not a function call, that is just a declaration of the function. You should have something like:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // ...
    std::string password;
    while (!validation::is_valid_password(password));
    std::string email;
    while (!validation::is_valid_email(email));
    // ...
}
```

There are many other problems in your code anyway... For example, if you are reading something inside the function `is_valid_xxx` (which is a bad design by itself because `is_`-type of functions shouldn't do anything except checking the values), you should pass the string by reference:

```
bool validation::is_valid_password(string &password);
```

Even if you don't plan to get the new value, passing something by value is a bad idea in this type of functions. Pass the value by reference to const:

```
bool validation::is_valid_password(const string &password);
```